# When do I need to use PXDBAttributeAttribute.Activate() for Caches?

Tags: acumatica

I realize that one does not always need to use PXDBAttributeAttribute.Activate(ViewName.Cache) for every view, but are there rules that dictate when to and not to use or need to use this function? Example being:

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        PXDBAttributeAttribute.Activate(ViewName1.Cache);
        PXDBAttributeAttribute.Activate(ViewName2.Cache);
    }
```